# dynamically added input fields and autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I've searched the net and am unable to find a solution.  Similar questions have either gone answered or I was unable to implement the answers.  I'm hoping someone here can help me!

So, I am trying to combine an autosuggest script with an add additional input field script. I have a professor field with an option to add more professor fields if needed. I can get the autosuggest to work with the first professor field, but the autosuggest doesn't run on dynamically added input fields.

The autosuggest script I am using is the AUSU jQuery-Ajax Auto Suggest

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/au...t-autocomplete

And the addinput script is from this tutorial: http://new2wp.com/snippet/jquery-add...t-form-fields/

Here is the javascript i have between the  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.ausu-autosuggest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$.fn.autosugguest({
className: 'ausu-suggest',
methodType: 'POST',
minChars: 2,
rtnIDs: true,
dataFile: 'data.php'
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var profDiv = $('#addprofblock');
var i = $('#addprofblock p').size() + 1;

$('#addprof').live('click', function() {

$('<p><div class="ausu-suggest"><input type="text" id="professor" size="25" name="professor[]" value="" autocomplete="off" /></div><a href="#" id="remprof" style="text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(profDiv);
i++;
return false;
});

$('#remprof').live('click', function() {
if( i > 2 ) {
$(this).parents('p').remove();
i--;
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

and here is a snippet of my code from the form I am creating:

```
<div id="addprofblock">
<p><div  class="ausu-suggest"><input type="text" name="professor[]" id="professor" size="25" value="" autocomplete="off" /></div>
<a href="#" id="addprof" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none">Add</a>
</p>
</div>
```

I've heard some people mention livequery as the solution, but I have trouble implementing it.  Thank you for any help you can provide!!

Answer (score 0):

You must bind the autosuggest function to the newly added input fields. In otherwords, each time you dynamically add a new input field, the autosuggest function must be set to work with said element.

Here is a tiny example:

```
function addInput() {
    var $input = $('<input type="text"/>');
    $('div').append($input);
    $input.autoSuggest({params...});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Live Query Plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) will do this work.